What is the name of a tool to rotate this ring?
I have this part (https://www.mcmaster.com/1116K25/):

with a central threaded ring with 2 slots. What is the name of a proper tool to rotate this ring? I used scissors, but surely there is something purpose built. I looked up spanner wrenches, but they are not suitable for this part.

try a search for retaining ring wrench

try making a tool from a hacksaw blade and PVC pipe

none required. Turn the nut or the bezel, the other will grab. Better to turn the nut and not mess up the seal. The notches are your level indicator.

@jsotola Retaining Ring Spanner Wrench seems to be the name I was looking for, e.g. https://www.newport.com/f/spanner-wrench.

@PhilSweet It is required. I have to replace the glass.

@PaulJurczak please write an answer ... add some pictures ... include a link to where the pictures came from

@jsotola I will, but the jackbooted moderators will most likely close this question as violating the prohibition of recommending specific brands.

@PaulJurczak the question does not ask for product recommendation

@Paul. No it isn't. Grab the nut from inside the tank. Hold the knurled bezel. That is how this type works - from inside the tank. If you can't access the inside of the tank with a socket or wrench, you have the wrong type. The slots just mark the fluid level.

I made several, as similar rings were used on many cars to secure fuel tank gauges.
I used a metal pipe of a suitable diameter, removing metal to leave the "ears".
Still got two made 40 plus years ago.

A fancier version is commonly used for optics adjustment, e.g. https://www.newport.com/p/LT30-WR

@PaulJurczak I would hazard a guess that fuel tank rings require much more torque than optics even if they are a similar diameter.

You are most likely right.

My solution is a camera lens spanner wrench like this one:

with selection of tips and span range 10 to 100mm. Easily found on eBay or AliExpress.
